# Fourier transform with an additional term in the power

Tags: fourier-transform

Consider this relation

$$\sigma(\omega_{I})=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} <\psi(0)|\psi(t)>e^{i(E_i/\hbar+\omega_I)t}dt$$

I know, by inverse Fourier transform, I can compute for

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} <\psi(0)|\psi(t)>e^{i\omega _It}dt$$

But I really have no idea how to take the $tE_i/\hbar$ power into account in order to determine $\sigma(\omega_{I})$; I just couldn't see the relation between the two integrals. Can someone help me?

Comment: I do not really see a difference between the two integrals. What exactly can you compute for the 2nd integral that you are not able to do for the first?

Comment: @KurtG. Using Python, I can only calculate for the second integral, of the form $\int f(t)e^{i \omega t} dt$, but this does not take into account the extra $E_i$ in the first integral that I want to determine.

Comment: Both integrals are of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{i\alpha t}dt$ if you can write a python program that works for $\alpha=\omega_I$ I simply don't get what the problem is when $\alpha$ is $E_i/\hbar+\omega_I$.

Comment: @KurtG. Oh thanks! I figure it out! Sorry for the trivial question!